# Is intuitionist logic two-valued?

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

On this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_bivalence :

> Intuitionistic logic is a two-valued logic but the law of excluded middle does not hold.

On this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_value :

> In intuitionistic logic, and more generally, constructive mathematics, statements are assigned a truth value only if they can be given a constructive proof. It starts with a set of axioms, and a statement is true if one can build a proof of the statement from those axioms. A statement is false if one can deduce a contradiction from it. This leaves open the possibility of statements that have not yet been assigned a truth value. Unproven statements in intuitionistic logic are not given an intermediate truth value (as is sometimes mistakenly asserted). Indeed, one can prove that they have no third truth value, a result dating back to Glivenko in 1928.[3]
>
> Instead, statements simply remain of unknown truth value, until they are either proven or disproven.

Could you explain to me what does it mean ? Is intuitionist logic two-valued and there is a subtlety, or is the first quote wrong as asserted by the second ?

Comment: As I understand these words, intuitionistic logic is not necessarily two-valued. It can be, though.

Comment: If a statement gets a value, its value is either "true" of "false". No statement can get both values (non-contradiction holds). However, unlike classical logic, not every statement gets a value (excluded middle doesn't hold).

Comment: > Is intuitionist logic two-valued and there is a subtlety, or is the first quote wrong as asserted by the second ?

The former. Statements have one of two values; just sometimes we don't know which. There is no third truth value.

Comment: There are models of intuionistic models which have, from the external perspective, more than two truth values, but this applies equally to classical logic and has nothing to do with the LEM or anything. How many truth values your model has can not be recognised from the inside (i guess you can add extra constants and axioms to force such an interpretation)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, give us a definition of what it means for a logic to be *$n$-valued*; then, we'll be able to tell whether intuitionistic logic is 2-valued or not.

Since there is no standard, widely-accepted notion or definition of "$n$-valued logic" at all, discussion regarding whether a given logic is $n$-valued or not tend to be very confused at best. The discussion on Wikipedia is no exception in this regard.

One could define many different notions of $n$-valuedness. Below, I consider four possible such definitions.

1. In [algebraic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_logic), one has a notion of *$n$-valued semantics*. This is not the definition we have in mind when we say that classical logic is 2-valued, since, while classical propositional logic has a complete 2-valued semantics, it also has a complete 4-valued semantics, where the four possible truth values are the sets $\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}$, conjunction is interpreted as intersection, and the negation of $x$ is interpreted as the relative complement $\{1,2\} \setminus x$. Saying that classical logic is therefore a 4-valued logic would be weird and confusing, to say the least. On the other hand, intuitionistic logic cannot have a complete $n$-valued semantics for any natural number $n$.
2. We could also try to pin down the notion of $n$-valuedness internally, without committing to a particular semantics. E.g. one could say that a subsystem of classical logic has *no more than $n$ truth values* if $$\bigvee_{0 \leq i \leq n} \bigvee_{0 \leq j < i} (A_i \leftrightarrow A_j)$$ is a tautology, i.e. out of every $n$ formulas, at least two are logically equivalent. Then, as expected, classical logic has no more than 2 truth values since $(A_1 \leftrightarrow A_0) \vee (A_2 \leftrightarrow A_0) \vee (A_2 \leftrightarrow A_1)$ is a classical tautology, and is not $1$-valued since $A_1 \leftrightarrow A_0$ is not a classical tautology. However, using the disjunction property, one can again show that intuitionistic logic is not $n$-valued in this sense for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
3. The Wikipedia page links a Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy article, which implicitly uses another ad-hoc definition of truth value. The basic story is as follows: we can say that a logic "admits $n$ truth values" if we can find $n$ formulas $f_1(P),\dots,f_n(P)$ in one free propositional variable $P$, so that we can prove $f_i(P) \rightarrow \neg f_j(P)$ for all $i \neq j$, and for each $f_n$ we can find some formula $X_n$ for which $f_n(X_n)$ has a proof in our logic. In this sense classical logic admits at least 2 truth values: we can take $f_1(P) = P$, $X_1 = P \vee \neg P$,  $f_2(P) = \neg P$ and $X_2 = P \wedge \neg P$. Using a result from Glivenko's 1928 paper, one can show that it's not possible to extend this set $f_1,f_2$ with any third $f_3$ and $X_3$, even in intuitionistic logic: no "third truth value" is ever taken. Using later results of Rieger and Nishimura, one can prove a much stronger statement: for any 3 formulas $A_1,A_2,A_3$ in one free propositional variable $P$, at least one of $A_i \rightarrow A_j$ with $i \neq j$ is always an intuitionistic tautology. In this sense, intuitionistic logic admits only two truth values, as does classical logic.
4. There are, of course, systems that people traditionally call systems of [many-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-valued_logic), such as Łukasiewicz's 3-valued logic, or Belnap's four-valued logic. But these are just traditional names, and do not fall under any general definition of $n$-valued logic. In particular, intuitionistic logic is not usually included at all in the study of "many-valued logic".

Again, none of these definitions are standard or widely used across logic. This should answer your main question: there *is* a subtlety, namely that since "$n$-valuedness of a logic" doesn't actually have a standard definition, whether intuitionistic logic is two-valued or not will depend on the definition you choose to adopt.